# Reshape Numpy Array: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a method, `get_input_representation` that returns a numpy array

```
np.array = input_stack + input_buffer 


return np.array
```

In another a different part of the program, I call the above method, save its return value and reshape it.

```
state_rep = self.extractor.get_input_representation(words, pos, state)
reshaped_state = np.array(state_rep).reshape(-1,6)
```

However, I get:

> reshaped_state = np.array(state_rep).reshape(-1,6) TypeError: 'list'
>   object is not callable

I have also tried:

```
 reshaped_state = np.array(self.extractor.get_input_representation(words, pos, state)).reshape(-1,6)
```

But I get the same list object is not callable. Where is the error in my code and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: You imported `numpy` as `np`.  `np.array` is a function that is used to create a numpy array (class `ndarray`).  But you then rename this `np.array = ...`.  Now it no longer is a function, but the result of that first line.  The original `np.array` function is no longer available.

Comment: even if `np.array` is in a different file from the caller function?

Comment: Don't use a name that could confuse you or the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not be assigning default Numpy methods to a variable (even if it is inside a function) ie instead of `np.array = input_stack + input_buffer` and then `return np.array` you should have `return input_stack + input_buffer` in your function

Answer (score 0):

Would you need brackets instead of parens?

```
np.array[state_rep].reshape(-1,6)
```

I think you are trying to index into the np array right?

Comment: when i do this, i get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: Hm, so it seems you aren't passing an index to the array. Can you add more info about what `self.extractor.get_input_representation(words, pos, state)` and what that returns?

Comment: yes, `get_input_representation` returns a np array (see edited post, hopefully made more clear)

Comment: You shouldn't assign it to np.array, try just creating a basic variable like `output_list` or something and then returning that.